# MySQL full text search - no partial recognition

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm trying to build a keyword search tool based on mysql and I can only get results for full words while I would like to get results for partial matches too.

My db structure looks like this:
[image]

My db content looks like this:
[image]

This query works:
select * from chromext_keyword where matches (keyword) against ('Redmi')

But this one doesn't work (no result):
select * from chromext_keyword where matches (keyword) against ('red')

I tried with % but it did not solve the problem. I tried the natural language option as well as boolean but it didn't help.

Update with create table query:
CREATE TABLE `chromext_keywords` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`keyword` text NOT NULL,
`blacklist` text NOT NULL,
`category` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

and insert:
INSERT INTO `chromext_keywords` (`id`, `keyword`, `blacklist`, `category`) VALUES
(1, 'Redmi Note 10', '9,8,pro', '2'),
(2, 'Realme GT', '6,7,8,narzo', '2');

and I added full text:
ALTER TABLE `chromext_keywords`
ADD UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `chromext_keywords` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `keyword` (`keyword`);

I have also tried innoDb and Myisam

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Can you post your query? And the table structures using `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO`? And can you also post the query that you tried?

Comment: The wildcard for fulltext search is `*`, not `%` (and it works only at the end of words).

Comment: @ErrBon sure, I have added both create and insert to the initial description

Comment: @Solarflare thanks, I tried with * like 'red*' but it doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should check for Minimum word lenght setting  ..

in mysql the minimum length for full text search in limited  by the param

```
ft_min_word_len
```

and the defualt value is for words > 3

take a look at the related   docs

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Comment: Thanks, I do think I can modify this, I'm using shared hosting. I checked in the settings but couldn't find something to modify this. I have tried with 3, 4 or 5 chars but I get the same result so I'm not sure the problem is related to the min amount of chars.

Comment: There is also a list of words not available for match ...(stopwors) see ..https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the answer.

The following query works:
SELECT * FROM `chromext_keywords` WHERE match(keyword) against('(re*)') IN BOOLEAN MODE)

With multiple keywords:
SELECT * FROM `chromext_keywords` WHERE match (keyword) against ('(+red*+not*)') IN BOOLEAN MODE)

I still need to figure out how to cover spelling mistakes. If anyone has an idea, let me know.